# unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, gcc

I am trying to install gcc to run a C/C++ program in Visual Studio Code, but I am not able to install gcc.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

And it shows an error `Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

How can I resolve this error and install gcc?

Comment: You updated the database but did you update the softwares? sudo apt upgrade?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1397874/edit) to show the complete output of `sudo apt update` AND complete input/output of any apt action showing the error.

Comment: Yes, please post the output of `sudo apt update` so that we can identify where the issue went wrong and provide an accurate answer.

Comment: A similar error that a user had is also on this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215399/cannot-install-or-uninstall-with-apt/1215407#1215407

Answer (score 1):

First, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then, run:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Please post any errors.